# Do all JavaBean properties have to use both getters and setters?

Tags: java, javabeans, setter, getter, getter-setter

> The class properties must be accessible using get, set, is (can be
>   used for boolean properties instead of get), and other methods
>   (so-called accessor methods and mutator methods) according to a
>   standard naming convention.

Doesn't this break the rule of encapsulation? After all if every private property has a getter/setter doesn't that make it not encapsulated?

Or do you have to use at least one for each property? either set, get, or both but never none?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confusing the term "property" with "instance variable". A property is that which you can set and/or get from outside the class. In Java, a property is created by having a private instance variable used through accessor methods (setter and/or getter). In JavaBeans, you can have private instance variables without a getter or a setter, but that makes it just an instance variable, not a property.

Comment: Ohh can I think of it this way? "properties are instance variables that are going to be accessed in some way by other classes"

Comment: @CodeCrusader ...by other classes THROUGH setter and getter methods. If you don't create a setter or a getter for that instance variable, then it's not considered to be a property.

Answer (score 0):

You must atleast have setter for your property to avoid null value when you access the value.

Yes though the property is private your set/get methods are public and hence you are allowing others to access your property. But in your setter/getter method you can add your own conditions to keep your property encapsulated rather exposing it public to all depending upon your requirement.